# Could we have LQ actions on late answer reviews?

Tags: feature-request, review

I find that many of the 'late answer' posts cry out for the actions in the low quality post queue. I'd like to avail myself of those standardized comments, even if I can't have a 'free' delete vote.

Mayhap what I really want is the LQ canned comments available *whenever I vote to delete*.

Comment: Canned comments for everyone! They taste better than SPAM!